# Keyboard repeats key presses

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, hardware

When I type "fast" the key presses are repeated randomly.
So for example "hello there!" becomes "helloo theere!".

This happened back on Ubuntu with GNOME and KDE and recently I switched over to Kubuntu, however the problem persists :/
Doesn't work on Live Fedora 29 either.
I'm using the Lenovo X380 Yoga.

This problem doesn't occur on Windows 10.

Drivers and BIOS are up-to-date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Seems like I've started having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that in Settings - Universal Access - Typing - Repeat Keys - there you can adjust Delay and Speed.